# How to get mysql to use the current effective linux user as the default user in mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux

If I login to a linux system as user alex, then change to user bob with su - bob, then as bob run mysql with no username arg specified, mysql will report (select user();) the user is alex.

I know I can do mysql -u bob to change the user, however I'm wondering if there's any way to configure mysql to use the current effective user (user reported by whoami) who ran the command mysql, bob in this example, to be used as the default when no username arg is specified to mysql? Thanks for any input.

Example:
Login as user alex

```
[alex@gc-instance-1 ~]$ mysql -e 'select user()'
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| alex@localhost |
+----------------+
[alex@gc-instance-1 ~]$ su - bob
Password: 
[bob@gc-instance-1 ~]$ mysql -e 'select user()'
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| alex@localhost |
+----------------+
[bob@gc-instance-1 ~]$
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1` is working as expected for me.

Comment: Sorry should have specified: Server version: 5.5.51-MariaDB MariaDB Server. Running on CentOS 6.8 via Google Compute Engine VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't it work to create a .my.cnf file in the home directory of bob and put

```
[client]
user=bob
```

Alternatively you can also put password. Eg.

```
[client]
user=bob
password=1234
```

Then change the file permissions to read/write by owner (600)

Also explained at [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html)

This way, you can just write 'mysql' and login without entering the password also.

PS. strangely in my system it uses the username of the whoever I became using 'su -' I am not sure why it is different in your machine. Manual says it defaults to unix username...

Comment: Thanks Evren, this accomplishes how I need mysql to behave.

Comment: BTW Pachonk replied that it uses the su - username as well, not sure what's up with my system. WIll do some digging there to find out why it's behaving like this...